# Trying to run an Android project in IntelliJ: Error:Abnormal build process termination: Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, jvm

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

How to fix it?

Java version:

```
    $  java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME:

```
$  echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I also have JDK 1.8 installed...

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, with a 64-bit version of Java. What are you using that needs a 32-bit JVM, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general settings for your project, you need to specify the right SDK. You need to download the required java version, and then find the path to its home and then point to it in General Settings > Project > Project SDK. Likely, you need to upgrade to a newer version.